# How to display text in different lines using Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog?

Tags: javascript, xaml, user-interface, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

[image]I want to display a pop up message using this code.

```
var messagedialogpopup = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog('', g_message);
```

But the full message is not being displayed.After few words ... is coming.
1.How to increase the size of this popup?
2.How to decrease the font size?or
3.How to break the message to display in two different lines,so that user can see full message.

Comment: any pointers on this?

Comment: <Popup IsLightDismissEnabled="False" IsOpen="{Binding OpenPopUp}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50" ></popup>

Comment: use "\n" it ll go next line

Comment: if possible can you share ur printscreen.so that i can help u

Comment: I have attached it in my question itsellf

Answer (score 0):

For Example here i used \n for break the message to display two different line

```
msg.Content = "The Customer has an alert of STOP\nMemo:Do not trade with this customer\n A Manager or 2IC must authorise this hire contract,would you like to authorise now?";
```